# Android memory allocation for images

Tags: java, android

I have several small (when they are png) images for a game. When I load them as static resources (following the game framework I am using) I get an out of memory error. Reducing the number of images gets rid of the error. In total, the images use less than a megabyte of memory on disk. Do they generate the error because they are expanded in the memory to fit the size I want them displayed at -- a scaled version, depending on the screen, of 1500x1000? This means a 10kb file might use 1.5 mb. Have I misunderstood this? Is this why commercial games are forever loading images?

Finally, and most importantly, assuming that what I have said above is correct and image files take up a lot of memory in Android even if they don't on disk, how can I remove them from memory once they are used so that I can load other images?

Comment: "In total, the images use less than a megabyte of memory on disk" -- since images are highly compressed on disk, you have very large images.

Comment: An 1500x1000 pixels sized image with transparency consists of 4 channels, each channel using 8 bits (1 byte) per pixel to store data uncompressed. Thus, this image would need 1500 x 1000 x 4 bytes of free memory (roughly 5.72 MB).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise that each image would take about 5 MB. Is this the case even if the image is just a single colour?